# Get Adobe DTM to work with page load rules in Angular

Tags: angularjs, adobe, adobe-analytics

Basically, I'm trying to find a way to efficiently fire tags using Adobe DTM in Angular without having to change the page. We have an exceptionally long elevation cycle so having to add `_satelitte.track()` to a page to get a new tag to fire would severly limit the benefit of using DTM. I'm primarily concerned this would be necessary in the case that I'd want to only fire tags in certain situations so I wouldn't be able to use the already existing rule in place.

I believe that `_satellite.pageBottom()` is what tells the satellite object that a page load has occured. I'm attempting to call _satellite.pageBottom() to mimic a page load any time the route changes.

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/one', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
        controller: 'Data1Controller'
    }).when('/two', {
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: 'Data2Controller'
    }).when('/three', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
        controller: 'Data3Controller'
    }).when('/four', {
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: 'Data4Controller'
    }).when('/five', {
        templateUrl: 'form.html',
        controller: 'FormController'
    }).otherwise({
        controller: "Default",
        templateUrl: 'default.html'
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('CacheBusterInterceptor');

}).run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        _satellite.pageBottom();
    });
});
```

This has worked well for me in other situations where I want to mock a page load but it's not working with the `_satellite.pageBottom()` call and I am at a loss how I might get DTM to work in Angular without using the direct call rules. Any advice on getting either this way to work or another work around to having to make changes to the code on the page?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Just checking if you have found a solution, other than _satellite.track("") ?

Comment: @DallasClark So we opened up a ticket for enhancement request to decouple the pageBottom() call from knowing where the page loads. What we ended up doing was creating three tracking calls per route. One at a global level that will affect every site in a DTM property. One at a site level so it will only affect that specific site within a property (we use the site name). And last a unique page ID for the last tracking call. We believe this will be the way to touch the amount of code on the page the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a generic _satellite.track('pageLoad') direct call rule to work around single page app challenges. You don't have to change the page code that way. As long as the variables you need are accessible by DTM, you can run all your logic in the tag manager.

Edit for dynamic direct call rule:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(e, curr, pre){
     _satellite.track(current.$$route.originalPath);
})
```

or if you want to add a pagename in your $routeProvider config:

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{pageName:'Fantastic Home Page',controller:...,templateUrl:...}

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(e, curr, pre){
     _satellite.track(current.pageName || 'whoops no pageName');
})
```

Comment: Brett, thanks a lot for the answer. I definitely see this as a possibility but it also seems to be a solution that will require that someone with JavaScript experience helps with every rule that won't be a global rule. I was mostly playing with adding the _satellite.pageBottom() to the routing so that more (non-IT) people can also work on some of the code.

Comment: You could modify it to handle a route name to create direct call rules against. See modified answer.

Comment: Brett, that's a really good idea. I think the optimal solution for us will be to have two track() calls. One for global rules and one for a specific page so that each rule created doesn't have to target specific pages but that it can if necessary. This definitely sent me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe DTM allows for firing rules based on popstate or hashtag change.  The best approach is to setup your rules based on these events and if your app supports deep linking then also setup page load rules based on the deep link URL's.

Comment: Actually it should be pushState instead of popstate.  In the Adobe DTM dashboard, when creating a New Rule, navigate to EventType and you have the option of selecting "pushState or hashchange".  This is a much better first-step approach (as long as routing is correctly set up), since you don't have to crack open the app to implement it.  Obviously, to implement a more robust tracking system you'll have to do more work.